# Joomla back end is unstyled

Tags: joomla-4.x, css, backend

I have an odd problem. I have a Joomla 4 website whose back end won't load the CSS/JS. I've tried deleting my browser cache, rebooting, etc.

I was doing some things in MAMP earlier today while working on a completely different website on a local server. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Googling the problem brings up the double Gzip problem. I have all the Gzip code commented out on my .htaccess file. And anyway, this site has been working fine up until today, and I haven't messed with it recently.

Any idea what I could have done to cause this? I'm working on a Mac with macOS 14.1.2, but the site with the broken back end is on a remote server.